# How to hide survey respones?

Tags: 2013, survey

How can I remove all links to survey responses (summary.aspx, allitems.aspx) from overview.aspx for users? I only want the "survey owner" to see the answers. Normal users should only be able to answer questions. [image: Is it possible to remove these links?]

Comment: If you set the permission correct, are you sure that users with lower permission get those links?

Comment: They don't get the settings link but all the others.

Answer (score 2):

If you were worried about colleagues seeing things they shouldn't there is setting within the survey list options that you can use to ensure people only see their own entries.  So, with this applied, if they did the pages mentioned above, they'd only see their own submissions.

Otherwise, if this isn't sufficient you can probably use a CSS snipped to hide those boxes.  Locate the selector with browser dev tools and set its display to "none."

Comment: I know that they only see their answers (when option changed in settings) but I want to "clean up" the page and hide unnecessary links. I'm not able to edit the page to add some css. I can switch to edit mode but there is no way to save the page.

Comment: Can you please update your question with a illustration picture?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure this would help, but you could try to create a new view on the survey.

[Creating custom views on Survey in Sharepoint](http://nishantrana.me/2008/11/25/creating-custom-views-on-survey-in-sharepoint/)

---

You have to set the permission on the survey.

1. Go into the library
2. Advanced settings

The advanced settings page allows you to configure who can see what responses and what they can edit. Note: Edit here means changing their votes after they submit, not editing the survey or web site. The fact they have contribute means they can add (submit) votes

- [SharePoint Survey Permissions Explained](http://www.collaboris.com/blogs/collaboris-blog/john-instone/2013/10/19/sharepoint-survey-permissions-explained#.U-nWY_l_sRo)
- [SHAREPOINT SURVEY PERMISSIONS PART: 1 - RESPOND TO A SURVEY BUT DO NOT EDIT SITE CONTENT](http://www.sadev.co.za/content/sharepoint-survey-permissions-part-1-respond-survey-do-not-edit-site-content)